# WooCommerce - how to disable redirect after place order

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

I trying to make all in one page for my checkout.
My issue is in checkout page when clicking on place order button, a redirect to payment page will happen.

is there a way to disable the redirect after placing the order successfully, to avoid moving to the next page?

Comment: It depends on your Gateway. some gateway doesn't redirect on another page and some do redirect.

Comment: After placing order you dont want to redirect to thankyou page? Its unclear what you want. Also what payment u are using ?

Comment: im using a local payment called Meshulam. what i trying to do is after clicking the place order button order will be created but no redirect at all. cause i want to insert payment with iframe in the same page as checkout is.

Answer (score 0):

you can change redirect page by using the below code..

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_order_received_redirection_to_my_account' );
function woo_order_received_redirection_to_my_account() {
    // Only on "Order received" page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        global $wp;

        // Get the Order Object
        $order = wc_get_order( absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']) ); 

        // My account redirection url
        $my_redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );

        // if you want to redirect cart page...
        // $my_redirect_url = home_url( 'checkout' );

        wp_redirect( $my_redirect_url );
        exit(); // Always exit

        
    }
}
```

Comment: can i have no redirect? after order is created i want to insert to the same page my payment page via iframe.

Comment: just replace your page url from this variable

 $my_redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the redirect by omitting / nullify the `redirect` from the payment gateway process payment results

to remove from all payment gateways you can use the hook `woocommerce_payment_successful_result`, so for example

```
function remove_woocommerce_payment_successful_redirect( $result, $order_id ) {
    $result['redirect'] = false;
    $result['messages'] = '<div>Show something here</div>';
    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result', 'remove_woocommerce_payment_successful_redirect', 10, 2 );
```