# Stop redirect to thank you page and get the order information into woocommerce

Tags: redirect, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to display a thank you message on the same checkout page. that’s why how can I block/stop redirection to thank you page and get the order data into the checkout page? is any jquery event or function available right there?

jquery event or function

Comment: Checkout cant be empty by default. Also depends on what kind of payment method u are using. Also what will happen if payment didnt pass ? By default the order is created and the client can try again or change paymenth method. Its not simple to modify it by the current description. Here is example how to change redirect - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781525/woocommerce-how-to-disable-redirect-after-place-order

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure why you want to redirect to the checkout page. If you prefer a custom URL, this is a [snippet to redirect the WooCommerce customer to a custom page upon a successful checkout](https://www.businessbloomer.com/resolved-woocommerce-redirect-custom-thank-page/).

If that's not the case, you can still re-adapt that snippet, and redirect back to the checkout page instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_redirectcustom' );
  
function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
    exit;
}
```

The big issue with this, is that once the cart is emptied, WooCommerce doesn't allow you to access the checkout page. It redirects you to the Cart page instead.

So, you also need this workaround:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_redirect_empty_cart', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review_expired', '__return_false' );
```

... you can find out why and a little explanation [here on Business Bloomer](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-show-checkout-even-if-cart-is-empty/). Basically, WooCommerce doesn't allow you to access the Checkout page when the Cart is empty as no action can be taken and the customer may get lost. The two lines of PHP above are a way to avoid this default redirect and make sure you can access the Checkout page even if it's empty.

Now that you can access the Checkout page when the Cart is empty, you need to print the order information which is usually displayed on the thank you page.

What you could do is... include the thank you page content if the checkout page URL contains an URL parameter. Lots of workarounds in here, but if this is what you're asking then we need to change the first snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_redirectcustom' );
      
function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
   wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'order-received', $order_id, wc_get_checkout_url() ) );
   exit;
}
```

Now, we can hook on top of the Checkout page, and include the thank you page content in case the URL contains a parameter:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_checkout_thank_you', 1 );

function bbloomer_checkout_thank_you() {
    global $wp;
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wc_get_template( 'checkout/thankyou.php', array( 'order' => wc_get_order( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) );    
    }
}
```

I didn't get much time to test this, so let me know via the comments :)